# Is it possible to get a list of all links with a class on a webpage?

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

There are a *lot* of links on a webpage.

The ones I want to make a list of (there will always be **exactly** 22) all have the same class

> "name notranslate":

[image]

Is it possible to get a list of all the links with that class? Or at least everything after   the "Href"

This program is written in C#.

I tried a for loop with web.Document.GetElementByID (web is the name of the webBrowser control) but that just did nothing.

Comment: Html agility pack... (Accidental Taylor Swift reference too?)

Comment: Sorry, I've hever heard of HTML Agility Pack, what should I do with it? Also, what's the reference? I don't see it (That being said, I don't listen to her songs)

Comment: Google it, its a open source tool you can use to manipulate html in c#, the reference is Taylor Swift has a song called 22 (or so I've heard)

Comment: Oh, no that's actually how many links there are. I'll check it out, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)

```
var web = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb();
var doc = web.Load(url);
var list = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@class='name notranslate']")
               .Select(a => a.Attributes["href"].Value)
               .ToList();
```

Comment: Is "Doc" supposed to be replaced with my webbrowser name? If it is, the program errors out.

Comment: @Minicl55 No it is of type `HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument`

Comment: How do I insert that into my program? I have installed HTML Agility Pack and I don't see it in the toolbox.

Comment: I now get this error when it passes over the the 'var list' line (it compiles fine): http://puu.sh/44XeM.png.

Comment: One last question, how do I click list[0], list[1], etc...?

Comment: Click list[0]? It is a `List<string>`, not a windows or webforms-control. I don't get you...

Comment: How do I make doc navigate to list[0]? I assumed it would be doc.Naviage(url) but it isn't.

Comment: @Minicl55 It is a library to **parse** html pages. You can not navigate to something. Use webbrowser control if you want to navigate to some site(to display the page to user). If you want to get the content of that page and make some processing on it, you see what I did in the code `web.Load(url);`